# match an alternative url - regular expression django urls

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I want a Django URL with just 2 alternatives `/module/in/` or `/module/out/`

I'm using

```
url(r'^(?P<status>\w+[in|out])/$', 
'by_status', 
name='module_by-status'),
```

But it matches other patterns like `/module/i/`, `/module/n/` and `/module/ou/`.

Any hint is appreciated :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `r'^(?P<status>in|out)/$'`

You need to remove `\w+`, which matches one or more alphanumeric characters or underscores. The regular expression suggested in bstpierre's answer, `'^(?P<status>\w+(in|out))/$'` will match `helloin`, `good_byeout` and so on.

Note that if you use the vertical bar (pipe) character `|` in your url patterns, Django [cannot reverse the regular expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse). If you need to use the url tag in your templates, you would need to write two url patterns, one for `in` and one for `out`.

Comment: @bluefish thanks, I’ve updated the answer to mention the limitation

Answer (score 1):

You want (in|out), the [] you are using indicate a character class containing the characters 'i', 'n', '|', 'o', 'u', 't'.

Comment: you suggest like this?: ^(?P<status>\w+(in|out))/$'

Comment: request to: /status/in/ django says: The current URL, /status/in/, didn't match any of these.  ^(?P<status>\w+(in|out))/$'

Comment: Ok, I guess I need more context. Do you have a higher-level urls.py? If so, is it stripping the /status/ off the front? If not, you probably want '^(?P<status>\w+/(in|out))/$'

Comment: Appreciate this explanation. I'd totally forgotten about this distinction.